# Using the Live tracking with internal GPS?

Tags: qgis, gps, software-recommendations

We have some Panasonic ToughPads (FZ-G1) with a GPS a module built in.

I know where it is and can locate in it in COM 3 and it connects, registers a signal, shows satellite locations, but refuses to give me a any details. It also doesn't place a cursor where I am located on the map.

How does QGIS decide what Baud rate to use?

Is there a way I can manually set it?

or can anyone recommend a better plug-in?

Comment: Can you enable logging and have a look at the output NMEA strings to see what the issue might be.

Comment: Have you tried using the GPS information panel with gpsd?

Comment: Logging seems to be fine, can't see any problems within that. I can use other programs as well and I receive a long and lat. Just not on GQIS.

Comment: Which QGis plugin (if any) do you use?

Comment: I'm using GPS Tools

Comment: Have you tried `View -> Panels -> GPS Information`?

Comment: Yes....thats how I know it connects and registers a signal and shows satellites.

Comment: Long shot--what coordinate reference system is your other data using?

Comment: Other data is on OSGB British National Grid 1936, I presume it will capture in the same as the Vector layer I've created to track my points?

Comment: GPS raw data is always in WGS 84 lat/lon. But I have no problem showing my GPS location on a EPSG:3857 Web Mercator map with QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

You can try GpsGate  to relay GPS input over a virtual COM port with selectable baud rate. The [GpsGate Express Client](http://gpsgate.com/purchase/gpsgate_express_license) is free of charge.

It works for me with a Garmin device connected via USB inside QGIS.

Comment: I cant get it to work. It finds the GPS but then QGIS won't connect to it.

Is it best to emulate a new serial port? Can you suggest the best output to use?

Comment: That's rather strange, because QGIS gets the satellite information, so it should get the position as well. A virtual COM would be the last chance I see. You could try http://www.visualgps.net/visualgps/ to see if that can read the location info.

Comment: Thanks GPS gate worked a treat. Used it for my panasonic FZ-G1 Tablet for global mapper. In setting for global mapper i used Garmin format, COM 1 with 9600 Baud rate. In GpsGate i made the active output Virtual COM1/Garmin Emulator, while the input was COM3, 9600 baud rate.